# Is it enough to just say `allow-hotplug eth0`?

Tags: network-interface, hot-plug

Are the following statements in `/etc/network/interfaces` equivalent?

```
allow-hotplug eth0
```

and..

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
```

That is, does `allow-hotplug` do everything that `auto` does and more?

Comment: I've looked there but not found an answer to this specific question.

Comment: It's there.  > allow-hotplug interface – Start the interface when a "hotplug" event is detected. In the real world, this is used in the same situations as auto but the difference is that it will wait for an event like "being detected by udev hotplug api" or "cable linked".

Comment: @mrc02_kr The question here if the difference between `allow-hotplug` alone and in addition to `auto`. The main practical difference according to my experience: The additional `auto` will add a timeout if the connection can't be established at boot time, which sometimes may be desired, but most of the time you don't want that. For example, for wlan connections, I strongly recommend to avoid `auto`.